# Index and match formula | find the user match highest value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel worksheet and I want to find the user **(A2:A6)** matching with the highest values in **(F2:F6)** and show it in another cell.

I think I can do it with this formula but i dont know how?

Here is my attempt:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$1,0,MATCH(MAX($B2:$F2),$B2:$F2,0))
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Your formula is working for me or at least the logic of your formula is correct.The ranges you used in your formula are all horizontal and you are looking to return a column position which is also correct. Have you checked if all values in `$B2:$F2` are valid numbers rather than text or other formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(MAX(F2:F5),F2:F5,0))
```

[image]

Comment: its show microsoft excel find error in the formula !

Comment: @Dr.androw -  Can you show the data? There's something off there, as it's working for me...

Comment: @Dr.androw - try replacing the `,` with `;`...? Some locales use semi-colons to separate, not commas.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what it might be...it looks correctly entered to me.